# How to scroll to last row of the last section in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a UITableView that fetches data from an array of an object say **Chats**. To scroll to the last row of this array I know that we use:

```
var chats = [Chats]()
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: [0, self.chats.count - 1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

What if I have an array of array (This is so that I can group chat messages into sections based on date). Now I have sections and then rows under that section.

```
var groupedChats = [[Chats]]()
```

How do I scroll to the last row of the last section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    let lastSection = groupedChats.count-1
    let lastRow = groupedChats[lastSection].count-1
    if lastSection >= 0, lastRow >= 0 {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: lastRow, section: lastSection), at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: This code will crash if `groupedChats` is empty. This code won't scroll if the last section has no rows.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the last section and last row, and scroll to last rows indexpath.

**Swift 5:**

```
let lastSection = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
let lastRow = tableView!.numberOfRows(inSection: lastSection) - 1
let lastRowIndexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRow, section: lastSection)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastRowIndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: you are missing a -1 in the second line

Comment: This code will not behave well if there are no sections or if the last section has no rows.

Comment: Obviously. You have to add proper conditions on section and row value. This just has the idea on the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Better create an extension for reusability :

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom(){

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(
                row: self.numberOfRows(inSection:  self.numberOfSections-1) - 1,
                section: self.numberOfSections-1)
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the table has no sections or if the last section has no rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
 func scrollToBottom(_ animated: Bool = true) {
        let numberOfSections = self.tblView.numberOfSections
        if numberOfSections > 0 {
            let numberOfRows = self.tblView.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections - 1)
            if numberOfRows > 0 {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows - 1, section: (numberOfSections - 1))
                self.tblView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't scroll to the last row in the table if the last section has no rows.